# Mysql prepareStatement is slow in a specific environment

Tags: java, mysql

My java application is slow only on customer platform ( has few data ). In Dev and Integration environment it's super fast ( with 10 times more data ).

I used Yourkit profiler to figure out the reasons. IT turned out that the MySQL's driver spend each time about 250ms on opening prepared statement ( the same operation is immediate on our internal environments )

```
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(String, int, int) ConnectionImpl.java
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(String) ConnectionImpl.java:4077
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(String) NewProxyConnection.java:213
org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList() FullTextQueryImpl.java:123
```

In the following query, opening Prepared statement takes 321ms , 1ms for the query and 0ms for closing it.

```
"Database.Prepared Statement.Open #19","17m 3 sec 234 ms - 17m 3 sec 555 ms","321","ajp-bio-11009-exec-3","NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement","SQL=""select courrier0_.ID as I...."" — Database=""jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parapheur_crfc_form?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8""   Class=""com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection""", "1"
"Database.Prepared Statement.Query #19","17m 3 sec 555 ms - 17m 3 sec 556 ms","1","ajp-bio-11009-exec-3","NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery","SQL="".....""   Class=""com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement"" — Database=""jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parapheur_crfc_form?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8""   Class=""com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection""", "1"
"Database.Prepared Statement.Close #19","17m 3 sec 556 ms - 17m 3 sec 557 ms","0","ajp-bio-11009-exec-3","NewProxyPreparedStatement.close","SQL=""select cour...""   Class=""com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement"" — Database=""jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parapheur_crfc_form?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8""   Class=""com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection""", "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any connection pool? If yes, try increase pool size.

If you check out MySQL JDBC driver source code from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=453814) and look at *com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement* you will notice synchronization:

```
 synchronized (getConnectionMutex()) { ... }
```

So the possible reason is that you are working in multithreaded environment where threads share single connection.

Comment: Yes i'm using a conenction POOL http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ with maxPoolSize=50

Comment: No it's a classic web application .. each http thread get a connection from the conenction's pool and release it ... I'll try to debug remotely with MySql's Driver Sources

Comment: I changed the version of the MySQL driver and it's OK now !  The implémentation of com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement is différent in the old driver ( 5.1.17 ) .. all the method was synchronized and there wasn't synchronized (getConnectionMutex()) { ... }

Comment: That's good. I think synchronization in ConnectionImpl was bottleneck in your case.